# MVC 3 Ignore requests from src attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, request, src

How can I detect requests from image when src="" ?

I want ignore them in Global.asax.cs (RegisterRoutes method)

Comment: Please put light on your question with an example

Answer (score 1):

You should first check Request.ContentType if it's image and then Request.FilePath if it's empty string